# Order of muliplication with or without times sign

Tags: definition

Is 6:2(2+1)=1 or is 6:2(2+1)=9 ?
I can't find any information regarding the order of multiplication without a sign. I'm sure that 6:2*(2+1) is 9, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: See also [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284801/why-when-dividing-by-2-pi-does-something-increase).

Comment: Is $:$ supposed to be $\div$?